# Is there any "Else Case" in the switch function to use?

Tags: php, switch-statement

A switch statement consists of "cases"...

But is there any "else" case for all other cases?

Have never found the answer to this...

ex:

```
 switch ($var){
   case "x":
       do stuff;
   break;
   case "y":
       do stuff;
   break;
   else: // THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE
       do stuff;
   break;
 }
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
default:
       do stuff;
break;
```

Typically the `default` clause should be at the very end of your other `case` clauses for general readability.

You may also want to reformat your `break` statements  in your code to look like this:

```
 switch ($var){
   case "x":  // if $var == "x"
       do stuff;
       break;
   case "y":  // if $var == "y"
       do stuff;
       break;
   default:  // if $var != "x" && != "y"
       do stuff;
       break;
 }
```

Extra information on the `switch` statement available [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) and [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/switch.php).

Answer (score 3):

As Dan said but in complete form if it helps...

```
switch ($var) {
    case "x":
        // do stuff
        break;
    case "y":
        // do stuff
        break;
    default:
        // do "else" stuff...
}
```

Comment: but it is good practice to always put a `break` if your intention is not to fall-through.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said. Not though that default might also be at the beginning or somewhere wildly in the middle:

```
switch (foo) 
{
case 0:  break;
default: break;
case 1:  break;
};
```

Surely you should not do this if not justified.

Comment: If you put default anywhere other that the bottom, any cases below it will be ignored.

Comment: @Simon: Why do you think that and don't try yourself? Here's what the standard says: 6.4.2/5 [stmt.switch]
"When the switch statement is executed, its condition is evaluated and compared with each case constant. [...] If no case constant matches the condition, and if there is a default label,
control passes to the statement labeled by the default label."

Comment: @Simon: My fail, for some rason I was assuming C. But it PHP, it seems to be the same: http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php#87959